# why i can't use the "administration command" in php when i am working in mongoDB

Tags: php, database, mongodb, collections

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method MongoDB\Driver\Manager::listDatabases()`

this error keep showing when i wanted to use the administration command for mongodb using php. I do not know whats the problem here and someone with kind soul please help me. The following codes is what i have tried which cause that error.

```html
<?php
$client =  new MongoDB\Driver\Manager(  'mongodb+srv://'.$_ENV['MDB_USER'].':'.$_ENV['MDB_PASS'].'@'.$_ENV['ATLAS_CLUSTER_SRV'].'/test'
 );
try{ 
    $dbs = $client->listDatabases(); 
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($dbs);
    echo '</pre>';
    // Or Nothing if you just wanna check for errors 
}
catch(Exception $e){
    echo "Unable to connect to Database at the moment ! ";
    exit();
}

$colecciones = $client->listCollections();
foreach ($colecciones as $col) {
    echo $col->getName();
}

?>
```

these two are the refereces that i used but is not working for me

[Get collections in mongodb with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49115927/get-collections-in-mongodb-with-php)

[Is there a way to test MongoDB connection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43977509/is-there-a-way-to-test-mongodb-connection-in-php)

what i am trying to do here is to make sure that my database connection is successful and also list out the collection name of my mongodb database.`

Answer (score 0):

The `MongoDB\Driver\Manager` provides a low-level API to MongoDB and does not offer methods to enumerate databases and collections. If you want to use the `listDatabases` and `listCollections` methods, you should be using the MongoDB library (`composer require mongodb/mongodb`), which offers the methods on its `MongoDB\Client` and `MongoDB\Database` objects:

```
$client = new MongoDB\Client(...);
var_dump(iterator_to_array($client->listDatabases()));

$database = $client->selectDatabase(...);
var_dump(iterator_to_array($database->listCollections()));
```

Note that the classes also offer `listDatabaseNames` and `listCollectionNames` methods if you are only interested in reading names without additional metadata.

If you want to be using the extension only, you'll have to create and run the `listDatabases` and `listCollections` commands manually:

```
$command = new \MongoDB\Driver\Command(['listDatabases' => 1]);
$cursor = $manager->executeCommand('admin', $command);
var_dump(iterator_to_array($cursor);
```